# cocos2d-x and run in android Studio

Tags: android-studio, cocos2d-x

i will run a cocos project in android Studio but when type command cocos compile -p android in cmd.exe say error in ndk.
and android.mk is :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/external)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/cocos)

LOCAL_MODULE := cocos2dcpp_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libcocos2dcpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes

# _COCOS_HEADER_ANDROID_BEGIN
# _COCOS_HEADER_ANDROID_END


LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static

# _COCOS_LIB_ANDROID_BEGIN
# _COCOS_LIB_ANDROID_END

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,.)

# _COCOS_LIB_IMPORT_ANDROID_BEGIN
# _COCOS_LIB_IMPORT_ANDROID_END
```

[my cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klDJ0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As now According to me you are using NDK 12 or greater.
These NDK by default add `arm64-v8a` architecture support. You don't have `libfreetype.a` file in `cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/android/arm64-v8a/` folder because cocos2d not generate by default, it slow down the compiling speed.

Solution is you can use NDK 11 or lesser
otherwise use latest version of cocos2d-x and enable ABI support to all arch `armeabi armeabi-v7a x86 arm64-v8a` instead of `armeabi` only

Some of concerning topic/issue

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/15713
https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/15566